# How augmentation increase number of images

Tags: pytorch, image-augmentation

I am confused about how augmentation increases the number of images. Can I calculate it?
Let say I have 10 images in batch

```
def augmentation():
    aug=transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(size=(248,248)),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(1),
        transforms.RandomVerticalFlip(1),
        transforms.RandomRotation(degrees=10),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize((0.2, ), (0.2, )),
                          ])
    return aug
```

After the augmentation in pytorch, how many images my model will be trained on in a single batch. I know at the end the data size remain same, but I want to know does it increase at any point in the pipeline